# Apa style bibliography with author year footcite

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

So for a report my teacher gave us exact prerequisite for the layout. He wants in text footnote citations in the author-year style and the bibliography in  the APA (5th) style. EDIT: The reference list should be numberd and sorted according to the appearence and I think corresponding to the footnote number.

Because I do not want to merge 5 `.doc` (MS Word) files from my group members and format everything in MS Word I need to get this to work in LaTeX.

Currently I am trying to get this to work with `biblatex` and Biber, but the combination of the two styles turns out to be very difficult to me. I am not set on `biblatex`. So, if it can be done with BibTeX or whatever, that is fine.

Comment: Do you need in-text citations, e.g. [...] (Doe 2013, p. 0) [...], *or* footnote citations?

Comment: Hi Ruben, I need footnote citations. The small number in the text and at the bottom of the text in the footnote section an author-year reference to it

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to solve your issue with `natbib` (which provides a bunch of new `\cite`- like commands, e.g. `\citep`, `\citet`, ...). I provided a new command called `\citef` (the suffix 'f' stands for footnote :-)

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ibid}{Ibid.}
  \let\@predcite\@empty
  \let\@currcite\@empty
\def\citef{\kernel@ifnextchar[\citef@{\citef@[]}}
\def\citef@[#1]{\kernel@ifnextchar[{\citef@@[{#1}]}{\citef@@[][{#1}]}}
\def\citef@@[#1][#2]#3{%
  \def\@currcite{#3}%
  \unskip
    \ifx\@currcite\@predcite
      \footnote{#1 \ifx\tempa\@empty\unskip\fi%
      \ibid\ifx\tempb\@empty\else\NAT@cmt #2\fi}%
    \else%
      \footnote{\citealp[#1][#2]{#3}}%
    \fi
  \gdef\@predcite{#3}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some Text\citef{article-full}\par
Some Text\citef[11]{article-full}\par
Some Text\citef[cf.][13]{booklet-full}\par

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

(Note that I also included an 'Ibid'-function, which is strongly recommended when using footcites.)

### Output

[image]

Comment: Well, that looks like it! I did not get your example working yet, but I will try later.
I almost got what I want myself with Biblatex. However, and I will edit this in the question, I also need numbers before the references.