# apacite bibliographystyle and footnote citations

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I seem to have lost the overview about my bibliographystyle and citation in footnotes. I am in dire need of your help. What I would like to achieve, is to have the bibliography in APA-Style, exactly like [here](http://www.mackichan.com/products/shells/apacite.pdf), and inside the text, to cite with footnotes that show the following: Author. (year), p. 375

Here is my the relevant code that I use so far. As you can see, I already use footnote citations, but unfortunately, without the desired bibliographystyle apacite yet. How can I combine the two?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,autocite=footnote, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblio}
```

And here an example of a citation command I use, where [23] is the page number:

```
\autocite[23]{corpore21}
```

Thsi gives me the following citation in a footnote: Pieth 1997, p. 23.

In advance, many many thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Please pare down your code to focus on what's relevant for your question. Surely you don't need to provide the entire title page and the names of all the chapters, right? What's currently missing are the citation commands you would like to use. Please edit your code to provide what's relevant.

Comment: Thanks for cutting out all the unneeded stuff, bringing the code down to just three lines. However, what's missing -- and really needed -- is a couple of actual citation commands.

Comment: What you need to provide is a [Minimum Working Example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) -- something that starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}`, and gives rise to the issue that you're looking to fix.

Comment: The problem is, that I would like to achieve an APA-like bibliography with the biblatex package, so that I still can use footnote citations.

Comment: I think I got it to work with this solution:

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145789/apa-style-bibliography-with-author-year-footcite

Comment: Since the OP seems to think it is an duplicate of [Apa style bibliography with author year footcite](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145789/35864) and the question is not entirely clear, I voted to close as duplicate.